# How many random numbers can Intel MKL generate once? Some limit seems to be exceeded

Tags: c++, random, intel-mkl

The following c++ code is almost the same as the example provided by Vector Statistical Library (VSL) in Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL). However, once the variable 'total' is larger than, say, 3*10^9, it will output

> MKL ERROR: Parameter 3 was incorrect on entry to vdRngUniform.

So I guess it implies that 'total' might be too large. But it is written in the manual that 'SFMT19937 method has a period length equal to 2^19937-1 of the produced sequence', which is far larger than 10^9.

I'd like to know what the upper limit really is, e.g., for double (I can't find any relevant information in the manual). And of course, any means to overcome this issue will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
......
MKL_LONG status;
VSLStreamStatePtr stream;
......
int main(){
vslNewStream(&stream, VSL_BRNG_SFMT19937, 777);
rnd_data = (double*)malloc(total * sizeof(double));
status = vdRngUniform(VSL_RNG_METHOD_UNIFORM_STD, stream, total, rnd_data, 0.0, 1.0);
vslDeleteStream(&stream);
......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-D7AD317E-34EC-4789-8027-01D0E194FAC1.htm the `vdRngUniform` takes a `const int` which has capacity to represent 2^31 non-negative values (on most modern platforms). 3*10^9 is larger than that, so you're likely passing some negative value to the function (i.e. signed integer overflow).